# Pass two different Chinese words in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In SQL Server, I have a table "a" as follow

```
ID     NAME_TYPE     NAME
1        老师         甲
2        医生         乙
3        厨师         丙
4        医生         丁
```

I have created a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[a_type]
    @NTTYP nvarchar(20)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN   
    SELECT * 
    FROM a
    WHERE NAME_TYPE IN (@NTTYP)
END
```

I will pass a string value `(老师,医生)` to `@NTTYP` into the stored procedure, and the expected result I want is

```
ID     NAME_TYPE     NAME
1        老师         甲
2        医生         乙
4        医生         丁
```

But the problem I am facing is the string value pass to stored procedure can't display the result that I want, below is my stored procedure result shows

```
@return_value = [dbo].[a_type]
                       @NCTTYP = N'老师,医生'
```

Can I do this way?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: what's the result you get? please add an example of the actual result to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Andreas Wederbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296452/andreas-wederbrand) gave you a tip to use prepared statements, however its syntax is not for *SQL Server* (I assume *MySQL*?). This is how prepared statement in *SQL Server* looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[a_type]
(
    @NTTYP NVARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
            , @SQLParams NVARCHAR(100);

        SET @SQL = N'
            SELECT ID
                , NAME_TYPE
                , NAME
            FROM a
            WHERE NAME_TYPE = @NTTYP';

        SET @SQLParams = N'@NTTYP NVARCHAR(20)';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @SQLParams, @NTTYP;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END
```

Let us know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, there is error Must declare the scalar variable "@NTTYP".

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add one line. Try now!

Comment: It return empty row, result as below: 
    DECLARE return_value int

EXEC return_value = [dbo].[a_type]
  NTTYP = N'老师,医生'

SELECT 'Return Value' = return_value

Comment: What's your collation in database? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Perhaps that's causing issues.

Comment: I think I will do in another way, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a prepared statement inside your procedure, something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[a_type]
@NTTYP nvarchar(20)

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN   
  PREPARE mySelect FROM 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE NAME_TYPE IN (?)';

  EXECUTE mySelect USING @NTTYP;

  DEALLOCATE mySelect;
END
```

Comment: I try to create the procedure, there is an error show, Incorrect syntax near 'mySelect', at this line PREPARE mySelect FROM 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE NAME_TYPE IN (?)';
I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Sorry, saw the tag "stored procedure" and just assumed MySQL. Way too tired to answer on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from a website that solve my problem, the link is :
http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/passing-multivalued-variables-stored-procedure

Then I recreate my store procedure as below :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[a_type]
 @NTTYP nvarchar(20)
AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN   
 SELECT * 
 FROM a
 WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + NAME_TYPE + ',', ',' + @NTTYP + ',') > 0
END
```

Now I can pass in string value or array like 老师,医生, and able to get the result I want.